# Django: Only run once when multiple objects created or on `save` when only one object is changing

Tags: python, django, database

I have two models in a Django application, one being a collection of the other:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    syllables = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...
    def set_statistics(self):
        """Computationally heavy task to set or update all document statistics
        including `syllables`"""
        ...

class Section(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

For every section, there is a computationally intensive function to calculate the `syllables` (among other statistics) for the aggregated text from each section. I would like to run this `set_statistics()` function for the document as few times as possible.

Ideally, things work work like this:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    ...
    # This doesn't seem to actually work when adding objects with an admin inline
    def bulk_create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Section, self).bulk_create(*args, **kwargs)
        self.document.set_statistics()
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Section, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.document.set_statistics() # This runs once for every section, I want
                                       # it to only run once if there are multiple
                                       # sections being added at the same time
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way since there is no way of knowing if there will be more sections to be added or not. You may consider a scheduled job to update documents.

Comment: Why not move this a level higher? What I mean to say is why override save method of Section model. You can check in the view itself if there are multiple sections being added and then run set_statistics accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ADMIN INLINE SOLUTION**

You can use the function save_model in the ModelAdmin of document ([django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)) and call the function set_statistics after saving the model (you can add optimization by checking if the number sections for the document )

```
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(DocumentAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        obj.set_statistics()
```

**GENERAL SOLUTIONS**

In the view for creating Sections call the function after saving the sections

OR

Set up a scheduled task that runs daily for instance (or more/less frequently if needed) to call set_statistics on the documents.